# Is it stable to run Drupal 7.8 on php 5.3.8?

Tags: 7, migrations

I would like to make use of php 5.3.x built-in fastcgi functionality and therefore I would like to migrate from php 5.2.x to php 5.3.8.

Is it stable to run Drupal 7.8 on php 5.3.8 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In fact, it is recommended to do so.